# Parse Actionable Notifications Not Sending from iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I have tried adding in Actionable Notifications for my Parse app, iPrayed 4 U.  In the app, someone can "Pray" for you by clicking a button.  Doing so runs a Cloud Code that includes a category for the APNS payload.  In my AppDelegate I have:

```
  if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
        {UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
            UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

            UIMutableUserNotificationAction *acceptAction =
            [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];

            acceptAction.identifier = @"THANKS_IDENTIFIER";

            acceptAction.title = @"Say Thanks";

            // Given seconds, not minutes, to run in the background
            acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
            acceptAction.destructive = NO;
            acceptAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

            UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *inviteCategory =
            [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];

            inviteCategory.identifier = @"TAGGED_CATEGORY";

            [inviteCategory setActions:@[acceptAction]
                            forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
            NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:inviteCategory, nil];

                                 UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
                                 [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];

                                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                                  registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

            [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
  completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"THANKS_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        [self handleAcceptActionWithNotification:notification];
        NSLog(@"Handled");



    }
    // Must be called when finished
    completionHandler();
}
-(void) handleAcceptActionWithNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification {
    NSLog(@"SendingThanks");
    PFUser *me = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSString *theirname = me[@"additional"];
    NSString *myAlertString=notification[@"loc-args"];
    NSLog(@"%@", notification);
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"thankYou"
                       withParameters:@{@"recipientId": myAlertString, @"theirName": theirname}
                                block:^(NSString *success, NSError *error) {
                                    if (!error) {
                                        // Push sent successfully
                                    }
                                }];

}
```

So, I run to testing.  When someone prays for me, I get the notification on my iPhone, drag down and there is the "Say Thanks" button.  I click it, but nothing happens.  Here is the kicker.  Normally I would say, "Well, I messed something up, start debugging".  However, I also have an Apple Watch.  When I click the Say Thanks button attached to the notification on my Watch, it sends the Push, vs. doing nothing when I click the same button on my iPhone.

Any thoughts as to what is going on here?

UPDATE:

In console, when it fails, I get:

```
[Error]: The request timed out. (Code: 100, Version: 1.8.2)
2015-10-08 13:42:49.424 iPrayed[2231:712503] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.463493 seconds.
```

Eventually I get a success call, but by that time it still doesn't actually send the Push.  Any idea why it is happening only when tapped from iPhone and not watch?

Comment: Honestly, I have no Idea ;-)
Do you have taken a look on the requests? (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/wiki/Network-Debug-Tool has been very helpful for me!)
Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you call `completionHandler()` before `PFCloud` finished. You need call `completionHandler()` in `completionBlock`

Do this.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"THANKS_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        PFUser *me = [PFUser currentUser];
        NSString *theirname = me[@"additional"];
        NSString *myAlertString=notification[@"loc-args"];
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"thankYou" withParameters:@{@"recipientId": myAlertString, @"theirName": theirname} block:^(NSString *success, NSError *error) {
            completionHandler();
        }];
    } else {
        completionHandler();
    }

}
```